# Dependency management and build tool for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dependency-management, package-managers

I have many JS <strike>snippets and</strike> files shared across multiple projects. I have to either copy-past them into a single file for each project, or serve them as individual files on cdn. Both are bad ideas.

Is there any dependency management and build tool like Maven for JavaScript? Ideally it would take a set of js dependencies and build a single js file which can be served on cdn.

I can write a script to do that. But I'm looking to find if anything comparable to Maven exists for JS.

---

Update 2014: Based on answers here and my research following are most popular tools:

Bower, NPM, RequireJS, Browserify, Webpack, Grunt, Gulp

Comment: You might find this link to be helpful: https://x-team.com/blog/rollup-webpack-parcel-comparison/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), but that's kind of a different thing than Maven, and what you're asking it to do is different than Maven too. There are any number of JS combiner/minifiers, like [jekyll-combiner](https://github.com/matb33/jekyll-combiner) and a zillion others.

If you're *using* Maven, the [JavaScript Maven Tools](http://mojo.codehaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/) might be of interest. If you're not, I don't know of a unified way to specifiy, download, combine, etc. for arbitrary build systems. Some of the node.js stuff might be useful, but I've never used that outside of a node.js context, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks, does any of them combine/build multiple files to a single at build time?

Comment: @JohnS What does "at build time" mean? How are you building? I've used combiners from Maven at build time.

Comment: Which combiner you have used with maven, which one you think is better? And is there any of them which accept dependencies like maven instead of file path?

Comment: I'm googling as well, but I can't find out which one is the best or most common.

Comment: @JohnS There's no unified JS library dependency mechanism, let alone snippet mechanism, like there is for Java under Maven. I've used the [JavaScript Maven Tools](http://mojo.codehaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/), but that's about it lately. Other stuff I've cobbled together.

Comment: I ended up using Bower and RequireJS/Optimizer.

Answer (score 4):

http://webjars.org/ packages JS libraries as JAR files and makes them available under Maven.

[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) is not a replacement to WebJars; it complements it.[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) will use public JS files (on CDNs) at runtime, whereas Webjars will download the necessary files at build-time and have you host them yourself.

Because most JS files are not hosted on CDNs, I use Webjars to download the necessary JS files at build-time, and reference them using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). That way I get the best of both worlds.

Comment: WebJars are just zip files with all the static resources cleaned up. I like it a lot but people continue to underestimate maven to resolve their client side dependencies. Not sure why :-( Much better and elegant than using bower and download the whole freaking GitHub repo IMO.

Comment: I have made my choice for WebJars. I have viewed [few other options](http://centurion.nfors.com/w/programming/javascript/start#javascript_and_maven), but found WebJars most easy to start with.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look to [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). It's very flexible build tool for javascript projects. Used by jquery team and other big projects. It combine, minify, test, lint js files, wtitten in javascript, have dozens plugins for whatever you want