# LESS: How can I include (concatenate) a css file without being processed?

Tags: css, less

How can I include (concatenate) a css file without being processed by less?

I can use `@import (less) file.css;` but it processes the css file which is not desired. On the other hand `@import (css) file.css;` is just replaced with `@import file.css;`.

Why? Because I'm trying to include and minify Skeleton css files in project main styles file but Skeleton includes `body { font: 14px/21px }` which is processed by less and results in incorrect font size.

Comment: You need to use some escaping:  http://www.lesscss.org/#-escaping

Comment: @cimmanon thanks, but I prefer not to edit external files which I install/update with bower.

Comment: Give a try to some build tool, I think that this is not natively supported. I suggest Grunt.

Comment: @gustavohenke thanks, Grunt is a little complicated for me. in fact I have asked that question before :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334346/dependency-management-and-build-tool-like-maven-for-js

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to be clearer on your issue, but [on the LESS site, the first line about importing states this](http://www.lesscss.org/#-importing):

> You can import both CSS and LESS files. Only LESS files import
>   statements are processed, CSS file import statements are kept as they
>   are. If you want to import a CSS file, and don’t want LESS to process
>   it, just use the .css extension:

Which means simply neither `@import file.css` nor `@import (css) file.css` (a 1.4.0 version syntax) should be getting processed by LESS, as it is a `.css` file.

Now it appears you are using LESS 1.4, as you are referring to the newer syntax of `@import (css) file.css`. If so, in addition to the fact that `14px/21px` is (as I understand you) making a division that you do not want, then if the importing is not functioning correctly (perhaps due to a bug?), then maybe what you can do is turn on the strict math setting. [Currently, the notes for 1.4.0 state](http://www.lesscss.org/#synopsis):

> [W]e have introduced a strictMath mode, where
>   math is required to be in parenthesis...
>   In 1.4.0 this option is turned off, but we intend to turn this on by
>   default. We recommend you upgrade code and switch on the option
>   (—strict-math=on in the command line or strictMath: true in
>   JavaScript). Code written with brackets is backwards compatible with
>   older versions of the less compiler.

That would prevent the `14px/21px` from becoming `font: 0.6666666666666666;` on output in LESS 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use the 'inline' reference.

```
@import (inline) 'file.css';
```

This will pull in the css file content as is without processing it.

See http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-inline