# Is having an extra reset.css in the head good?

Tags: css, less, reset

I was wondering. I often have a global.css and a separate reset.css in my head. But isn't it just better / smarter to combine the reset in one css file?
Does using less make a better solution?

Comment: Less files means less server requests. So yes.

Comment: Were LESS and SASS often speed up the workflow, combining the two CSS files is first and foremost a great way too lessen the load time of your website. Less HTTP requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better / smarter depends in the first place what your focus is. Do you focus on fast loading, user experience, etc? 
Of course fast loading also influences user experience too. Reduce your code to only what you need will always be the first step. LESS can help you to reduce the total bytes of CSS you will need. Also caching plays a important role. Inline code can't cache but loads fast. As mentioned by @scrblnrd3 extra HTTP requests will be relative slow.
Putting global.css and reset.css in one file reduce HTTP requests and can be cached if static. LESS can help you here too. LESS compile to one final CSS file mostly, while your source files can be split and structured. In your example your main LESS file compiled to for example main.less can look like:

```
@import "reset.css";
@import "global.css";
```

See also: [LESS: How can I include (concatenate) a css file without being processed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030837/less-how-can-i-include-concatenate-a-css-file-without-being-processed)

For pure user experience you also will have to consider the above-the-fold portion of your website and use this to split your CSS in in-line parts and deferred load parts. If main parts of the code of your global.css not involve the above-the-fold portion of your website, split up the files or code can be a better solution. The risk of doing this will be to introduce a old-skool [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOUC).

Answer (score 2):

If it is in production, combine them. HTTP requests can be fairly expensive, and it will help your page load faster with one larger file and one less HTTP request. This will also have a large effect on total load times if you have a large global and a large reset file for each page.

However, if you're still developing, it may be beneficial to separate them so you can find, change, and add things with more ease